# translate a map from map server

Tags: localization, navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to reuse a map for localization. I load a saved map from the map server. Idealy i would like the map to be at the fixed coordinate origin(0,0). When I start the server though the upper left corner of the saved map is put into the origin. How can I move the map. In the corresponding yaml file I find a value for `origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` In the documentation I see that this the value of the lower left corner of the map. However if I edit this value, the map doesnt translate in the visualization.

What would be the way to go here?
I could publish a static transform for the map frame. But then I would like to publish this only once at start up or at certain circumstances ?For example if my localization in the map is too far off. I cant see how I to realize this in code. It seems to me to be a very standard problem maybe someone here can help me. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284088/translate-a-map-from-map-server/) by [Peter1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33821/peter1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way to go is with the `origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` parameter defined inside map.yaml, set to a negative number (in meters) such as `origin: [-8.0, -8.0, 0.0]` . If you have changed this value and it does not translate on rviz then ensure that "Global options" -> "Fixed Frame" is set as "map". You could post a link to your code or more details to reproduce the error, for me moving altering `origin` works.

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2018-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0